# Eclipse error upon workspace selection

Tags: eclipse, installation

On my quest to install and correctly set up Eclipse I have found myself a participator in the dirtiest of duels, duking it out with a multitude of foes that have stepped in at every turn to thwart me. For each of my adversaries I have picked myself up and returned to the ring several times, eventually emerging victorious after searching Google and querying friends for the weapons I needed to vanquish my opponents.

Now, just when I thought I had completed my quest and I make it to the Workspace Launcher pane, I get a sucker punch - another error message. When I check the log folder it left behind, I find what appears to be mysteriously encrypted clues on how to take down my latest opponent. I've pasted these clues below (the log repeats many more similar messages on duplicated names, far too much to paste without danger of falling asleep reading them). What does does all this mean, and how may I defeat my latest foe? You have my most sincere gratitude for your efforts to help me in this endeavor.

```
!SESSION 2014-01-24 22:11:06.412 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 2 0 2014-01-24 22:11:09.362
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.0.v20130327-1442 [733]
]
Component2: Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049 [403]
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says "Found components with duplicated names" .. This happens when two or more components/plugins register with same name and version. Here you can see 2 versions "org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049" and "org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.0.v20130327-1442". I think you have to get rid of one of those plugins.

Comment: It turns out the reason was that I had two different versions of Eclipse installed on my disk - Juno and Kepler. I deleted my Kepler version and reinstalled Juno. It worked after that.